# Comparing current date to future date in bash

Tags: bash, shell, date

I can convert a fixed date to an integer by:

```
todate=$(date -d '2021-11-14 07:00:01' +%s)
```

I can also retrieve the current date string by doing:

```
curr_date = $(date '+%F %H:%M:%S')
```

Now I would like to pass curr_date to be able to compare it to todate by doing something like:

```
now=$( date -d $dat +%s)
```

So I can later do something like:

```
if [ $now -ge $todate ];
... 
...
```

This, however, does not work. How do I correctly define *now*?

Comment: `then=$(date -d 'then-date-string' +%s) now=$(date +%s); if ((now>then)); then echo then is passed; else echo then is future; fi`

Comment: Put a valid shebang on your script and paste it at https://shellcheck.net for validation recommendation.